# REGEX - How to capture a group recursively?

Tags: regex, capture

> {"dir":"false", "bytes":158481, "parent_folder":"/Annie/FROM OLD DVDS", "name":"1.jpg"}, {"dir":"false", "bytes":382661, "parent_folder":"/Annie/FROM OLD DVDS", "name":"2.jpg"}, {"dir":"false", "bytes":1455205, "parent_folder":"/Annie/FROM OLD DVDS", "name":"3.jpg"}

This is my current REGEX string that captures only the first match:

```
(false.+\"name\"\:\")(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|png))(\")
```

I want to capture every name not just the first one. Currently it only parses 3.jpg the last one.

Outcome wanted:

1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg

Comment: Why are you doing this with regexp at all? This is (edit: almost) [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). Are you missing some square brackets? What language are you working in?

Comment: Yes. The output is JSON. But my problem is, there are times when it captures a folder, which makes the dir value - true. I'm hoping for a better alternative. My knowledge is very limited to JSON/JToken parsing. Language is C#. If possible, I would like to parse with either JSON/XPath/Regex only.

Comment: The thing is, you have an array of objects. Each object has a `dir`, `bytes`, `parent_folder` and `name` property. You simply want the `name` property of each. Find whatever JSON library you want to use with C#. Maybe [this page](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-json-string-in-C-Sharp/).

Comment: I'm just looking for a quick solution on regex if possible.

Comment: What are the constraints for capturing? You say you want to capture every name.  But it seems liek you're looking for a particular type of name. Do they have to be a certain extension? Also does the "dir" property have to be false?

Comment: A cardinal rule when giving an example is to show the desired return value.

Comment: @shockwave123, yes. Hence the extensions at the end. I just want it to find every match that it can from start to end.

Comment: @RuriRocks Also the dir has to be false as well? I posted an answer, i'll update it now.

Comment: `I'm just looking for a quick solution on regex if possible.` [You know what they say about RegExp](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/). You've made things hard on yourself.

Answer (score 0):

First of all... You won't be able to capture all names using a regex unless you know the exact amount of times the `name` property will appear. For example, if you knew the string is going to contain 3 `name` properties, than you could write a regex that looked like `.*"name":"(.*?)".*"name":"(.*?)".*"name":"(.*?)".*` which will capture 3 groups of names.

Your regex is not capturing the first name, it's actually catching the last name. This is because you are using a greedy quantifier along with a wildcard `.*`. You'll have to take into account that the `{`and `}` tokens indicate a new object. so you'll need to use  `[^{}]*?` instead to ensure you're only looking at one object at a time.  the `*?` quantifier is a lazy match so it'll only match as many characters as needed, unlike the `+` or `*` which will match as many characters as it can.

You could also utilize non-capturing groups `(?:)` to match on extensions without capturing them. The idea here is to make sure the only thing we are capturing is the value of the name. Unlike your current regular expression, which captures multiple groups. The final Regex looks like this:

`.*?{"dir":"false"[^{}]*?"name":"([^{}]*?(?:jpg|jpeg|png))"}.*?`

in C#, import `System.Text.RegularExpressions` for all of your regular expression needs. You can look for all matches of a regex using `Regex.Matches`. Loop through the resulting `MatchCollection` and extract all of the matches and captures from the matches. In your case, your code might look like

```
    string text = @"{""dir"":""false"", ""bytes"":158481, ""parent_folder"":""/Annie/FROM OLD DVDS"", ""name"":""1.jpg""}, {""dir"":""false"", ""bytes"":382661, ""parent_folder"":""/Annie/FROM OLD DVDS"", ""name"":""2.jpg""}, {""dir"":""false"", ""bytes"":1455205, ""parent_folder"":""/Annie/FROM OLD DVDS"", ""name"":""3.jpg""}";
    string search = ".*?{\"dir\":\"false\"[^{}]*?\"name\":\"([^{}]*?(?:jpg|jpeg|png))\"}.*?";
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, search);
    foreach(Match match in matches){
        GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;
        Console.WriteLine(groups[1].Value);
    }
```

Depending on your use case (as @adam was suggestion) it may be beneficial to isolate each object and use a Json Deserializer to convert the strings into a list of objects. Would be a lot easier to work with and much more maintainable and robust than relying on your own regex.